# Cannot open file for output (Matlab)

Tags: image, file, matlab, permissions, binary

I am having a problem in matlab and the problem is described as follows:

When i try to read an image ( I have several images) and write them to a specific folder, the matlab triggers an error saying

```
  Error using ==> imwrite at 394
Can't open file "\Temp\\inim735282.4716703009300000.jpg" for writing.
You may not have write permission.
```

May I know why this is happening?

this is the code where the problem occurs

```
mkdir('.\Temp');
temp_name =  sprintf('%.16f',now);
corner_file = ['\Temp\corners', temp_name,'.in'];
image_file = ['\Temp\inim', temp_name,'.jpg'];
out_file = ['\Temp\out', temp_name,'.desc'];
out_imname = ['\Temp\out', temp_name,'.desc.jpg'];
```

I tried to change it by omitting

```
mkdir('.\Temp');
```

moreoever, i direct the path in the folder to the folder by doing this

```
binary_path = 'C:\Users\cool\Documents\MATLAB\Experment\experiments\bag_of_words\Temp';
```

to read and and write in and out of the folder.

Can someone please help me figure out this problem?

Thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

Open MatLAB with admin privileges.

Comment: It does not work, it tried but it give me an error saying " Undefined function or method 'do_all' for input arguments of type 'char'." but when it is without admin privilleges, it runs until the above error triggered. the command line is " do_all('config_file_1')

Comment: is that a plug-in that you use? If its a plug-in did you forgot to add its path?

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions:

1. To generate a temporary output name use the command [`tempname`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tempname.html).

   ```
   temp_name = tempname();
   ```
2. To concatenate paths and file names use [`fullfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html).

   ```
   conrner_file = fullfile( '\', 'Temp', 'corners', [temp_name, '.in'] );
   ```
3. You should be careful not to mix '\Temp' and '.\Temp': as the first is an **absolute** path, while the second is a **relative** path to `cwd`.

**EDIT:**
How about:

```
temp_name = tempname(); % temp name + folder name in TEMP
corner_file = [ temp_name,'.in'];
image_file = [ temp_name,'.jpg'];
out_file = [temp_name,'.desc'];
out_imname = [temp_name,'.desc.jpg'];
```

Is it working now?

Comment: Shai, it does no good the changes I made. It could be coz of windwos 7 security properties.

Comment: unrecognized suffix ".jpg" the error is gone but another error coming which is "unrecognized suffix ".jpg" what does that mean?

Comment: Shai, it does work flawlessly however, the output is not expected. it gives a warming saying that "couldnt open out file". anyways thank you